# PGU(Phil's pyGame Utilities) - Access Main Update Loop

Tags: python, events, loops, pygame, pgu

So I am making an app in pygame using PGU. I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the main update loop. I have a nice looking interface with events working, however I also have some networking code that needs to happen every loop(to check to see if the server has sent me anything). How can I get my code to execute every loop?

I was thinking maybe in pgu there is some event that happens ever time, if so then I could catch this event, and execute my server-checking code.

If you guys need any additional info just ask, I can post my code if need be.
Thanks

Comment: PGU has a loop() function predefined for some of its objects, which is called every frame. Is your code small enough to include with your question, perhaps via Pastebin? I would be more able to help you if I could get a better idea of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Maythe has already mentioned this, but what you need to use is the app.loop function. So, say you have a function that will do everything you want to happen on top of the mainloop, called dosomething, you would do this:

```
myapp = gui.App()
myapp.init(widget=<your root widget>)
while True:
    dosomething()
    myapp.loop()
```

In fact, I looked at the pgu code online, and all that mainloop does is:

```
while True:
    myapp.loop()
    time.sleep(wait)   #this is just a routine wait each iteration you give it
```

So you really are directly adding code on top of the update function, without any unwanted side effects.

Comment: I was doing this literally a year ago lol, I figured it out eventually, but I have no idea what I did.

Bottom line, what I learned, DO NOT use PGU as a tool for a gui, use something sensible like pyqt.

Comment: Yeah that is more or less what I did as well. Pgu sucks. I did, however, work out an excellent way to embed pygame in tkinter.